# Cannot parse "#" sign in dialer

Tags: java, android

I'm making a custom dialer and everything till now was perfect. Now while testing, I saw that the "#" sign was not working properly. It shows on the dialer but while calling, it goes away. For eg, if I dial *121#, it becomes *121 when the call is being made through the stock dialer. Here is the code for my activity-

```
public class DialPadActivity extends Activity {

private EditText numberField = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initializeButtonArrowClickListeners();
}

public void dialButtonClick(View v) {
    int buttonId = v.getId();
    putNumberToEditText(buttonId);
}

public void buttonPhone_click(View v) {
    if (numberField != null) {
        String phone = numberField.getText().toString();
        String uriString = "tel:" + phone;
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(uriString));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public void putNumberToEditText(int buttonId) {
    switch (buttonId) {
    case R.id.dial_button0:
        putNumber("0");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button1:
        putNumber("1");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button2:
        putNumber("2");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button3:
        putNumber("3");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button4:
        putNumber("4");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button5:
        putNumber("5");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button6:
        putNumber("6");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button7:
        putNumber("7");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button8:
        putNumber("8");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button9:
        putNumber("9");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button_s:
        putNumber("*");
        break;
    case R.id.dial_button_p:
        putNumber("#");
        break;
    }
}

public void putNumber(String number) {
    if (numberField == null) {
        numberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.phone_number_field);
    }
    numberField.append(number);
}

private void initializeButtonArrowClickListeners() {
    ImageButton buttonArrow = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_arrow);
    buttonArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (numberField != null && numberField.length() > 0) {
                String previousNumbers = numberField.getText().toString();
                String numbersMinusTheLast = previousNumbers.substring(0,
                        numberField.length() - 1);
                numberField.setText(numbersMinusTheLast);
            }
        }
    });
    buttonArrow.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if (numberField != null) {
                numberField.setText("");
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Where am I doing the wrong?

Comment: You don't have a `break;` after `putNumber("#");`. Did you try entering something like `*123#11` ?

Comment: My bad for the `break;`. But it still doesn't work. Tried *121#11 but still the call went as *121 only.

Comment: so everything after the `#` symbol dissapears - right?

Comment: After and including the # :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");

For example:

```
String uriString = "tel:" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your # symbol with %23.

That is: `*121%2311` instead of `*121#11`

```
            String uri = "tel:" + "*6133%235345";

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(intent);
```

the output for this is : *6133#5345

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried it already. It shows 23 instead of the # in the number box and calls the same way. Means in the end it becomes *12123 instead of *121#

Comment: No, it is working I tried it and wrote but you had a solution anyways :)